# Table does not refresh

Tags: jsf, javabeans, objectdataprovider

I have a table that consists of rows of reports. A back bean method that is tied to a check box value change event is getting the row IDs and populating an array (rowsToBeRemoved) with this IDs. Another method gets this array and removes the object from reportlist class:

```
ObjectListDataProvider reportList = new ObjectListDataProvider();
List<RowKey> rowsToBeRemoved=new ArrayList();
Integer rowsToBeRemovedIndex = 0;

 for(RowKey rowToBeRemoved:rowsToBeRemoved){

            try {                
                System.out.println("rowToBeRemoved.toString()" + rowToBeRemoved.toString()); // outputs: rowToBeRemoved.toString()RowKey[0] 

                Report report = (Report) reportList.getObject(rowToBeRemoved);

                System.out.println("report.getId()" + report.getId()); //outputs: report.getId()199|


                Query resultQuery = queryGeneration(report.getId());
                List<String> dropTableQueries = resultQuery.getResultList(); // generated the queries to drop r tables


                for(int i=0; i<dropTableQueries.size(); i++){

                   String aDropTableQuery;
                   aDropTableQuery = dropTableQueries.get(i);
                    System.out.println("adroptableuery" + aDropTableQuery);// get single drop table query. outputs adroptableueryDROP TABLE r_199_0
                   entityManager.createNativeQuery(aDropTableQuery);
                    System.out.println("entitymanager dropTableQueries is invoked");//OK
                   reportList.removeObject(rowToBeRemoved);
                    System.out.println("removeObject");//OK
                    if (reportList.isRemoved(rowToBeRemoved)){
                        System.out.println("object removed");//OK
                    }                    
                    reportList.commitChanges();
                    System.out.println("commitchanges");//OK

               }
                reportJpaController.delete(report);
                reportList.removeRow(rowToBeRemoved);
                reportList.commitChanges();
                analyzerResultService.drop(report.getId().longValue());
                //rowsToBeRemoved.remove(rowsToBeRemovedIndex);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error("Cannot delete report with row key " + rowToBeRemoved + e);
            }
```

The code executes fine, removes the object from the reportlist but after that my table brings up a mixed reportlist. If I refresh the page it brings the reportlist in correct order, otherwise it doesn't. And if I try to delete a row in the mixed state it deletes the report as if it is in correct order, thus ending with deleting the wrong report. I hope I could explained.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is similar to what you're looking for: [How to refresh entire JSF page from the backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628722/how-to-refresh-entire-jsf-page-from-the-backing-bean)

This doesnt just refresh one part of the page though, but the full page.

Comment: do you mean I should implement Ajax4jsf?

Comment: your answer gave me the clue. There was a problem with table update in JSF. Instead of implementing Ajax I put 
onClick="setTimeout('#{user$recentreports.updateReportList()}',500}" to my table which triggers an already defined method in the backbean. And it solved my problem. Thanks a lot.